# QuickFIX doesn't validate the repeating group

Tags: c++, quickfix

I'm implementing a client-server set based on QuickFIX. When I try to send a message that contains a Parties repeating group, I get the Reject with the following description: "58=Tag not defined for this message type|371=447|"

The message type thet I try to send is OrderCancelReplaceRequest.

The code sample is:

```
FIX44::OrderCancelReplaceRequest order(FIX::MsgType("G"));

FIX44::OrderCancelReplaceRequest::NoPartyIDs party;
// 448-PartyID
party.set(FIX::PartyID("PartyId"));
// 447-PartyIDSource
party.set(FIX::PartyIDSource('B'));    
// 452-PartyRole
party.set(FIX::PartyRole(1));    
// 802-NoPartySubIDs
party.set(FIX::NoPartySubIDs(0));

order.addGroup(party);

...
```

If the message contains no Parties group, it's validated successfully by the server.

Moreover, it's validated successfully even if it contains the FIX44::OrderCancelReplaceRequest::NoAllocs group:

```
 FIX44::OrderCancelReplaceRequest::NoAllocs alloc;
 // 79-AllocAccount
 alloc.set(FIX::AllocAccount("Alloc Account"));
 // 80-AllocQty
 alloc.set(FIX::AllocQty(4.2));
 order.addGroup(alloc);
```

So, I see this problem only when I try to use the Parties group.

The config file for the server is:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=28663
SocketReuseAddress=Y
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=<some path here>/FIX44.xml
FileLogPath=QuickFixServerLog
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=EXECUTOR
TargetCompID=CLIENT1
FileStorePath=store
```

The config file of the client is:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=1
FileStorePath=store
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=<some path here>/FIX44.xml
HttpAcceptPort=9911
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=CLIENT1
TargetCompID=EXECUTOR
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
SocketConnectPort=28663
HeartBtInt=15
```

Upd.

The example of the request reseived by server (it's from the server logs) is:

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=234|35=G|34=2|49=CLIENT1|52=20150417-10:49:07.715|56=EXECUTOR|1=Account|11=Id123|38=11.11|40=1|41=OrigId321|44=4.2|54=2|55=Symbol|60=20150417-10:49:07|78=2|79=AllocAccount1|79=AllocAccount2|80=10|80=20|447=B|448=PartyId|452=1|453=1|802=0|10=185|
```

The response for that request is:

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=124|35=3|34=2|49=EXECUTOR|52=20150417-10:49:07.719|56=CLIENT1|45=2|58=Tag not defined for this message type|371=447|372=G|373=2|10=060|
```

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the actual message.  (Please make the field separators visible.)

Comment: Just a guess. Your `ValidateUserDefinedFields=N` might be interfering if you have user defined fields. Try makeing it Y and see. But as @Grant said, seeing the messages would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

I've updated the description with the messages' examples.

As for ValidateUserDefinedFields, i've tried it (as well as disabling all the other possible validation settings in the config file), but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are communicating with a FIX 4.4 server? The `<Parties> component block` was only added since 4.3, might be that you are communicating with a 4.2 server?

Comment: The server is 4.4, I'm sure.

Comment: I validated the FIX message [here](http://fix.aprics.net) and it doesn't see anything wrong with it. Did you write the FIX server using quickfix as well? If so, maybe you could debug it server-side, see what is causing the reject message?

Comment: If you have control over the server implementation, could you try adding `ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N` to the configuration?

Comment: Just a quick note, if you respond to my comments, please start your answer with @TT so that I get a nofitication (you will see what you can write in comments if you press the help-link next to the comment box)

Comment: @TT Thank you very much for your comments!
I've tried ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N, but, unfortunately, the result is still the same. 
The server is implemented using quickfix. I'm currently trying to debug it and will describe all the results of the debugging as soon as I complete it.

Comment: What I know is that the order of the fields a in group (repeating or not) is important. My guess is that the field `453` needs to come first in the [`Parties` component block](http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/compBlock_Parties.html) and that's what's causing the server to balk. The latest Quickfix/J configuration even has a `ValidateUnorderedGroupFields` ID to bypass problem with unordered group fields, but I found no such configuration option in the C++ version of QuickFIX.

Comment: Another try at a solution. In your download of the quickfix C++ package, search for the file `MessagesTestCase.cpp`. In that file, look for the `NoPartyIDs` string. In there is an example adding a `NoPartyIDs` group to a `FIX44::NewOrderCross` message. Apparantly this uses `FIX44::NewOrderCross::NoSides` as the container for the `NoPartyIDs` group. Maybe you could try and see if the same usage pattern is needed for adding party-ids to `FIX44::OrderCancelReplaceRequest`?

Comment: @TT Thank you, I've looked at the test example, but I still don't see any issues in my client code. The message that the client creates looks to be all right - the problem is on the server side as QuickFIX doesn't find an embedded field 447 in its data dictionary.

Comment: So if you log the message created on the client side, the `453` is before any of the other tags in the NoPartyIDs group (448,447,452,802)?

Comment: @TT Yes, on client side the order is 453, 448, 447, 452. But the server receives the same message with all the fields set in the increase order...

Comment: @TT Thank you very much! Your idea regarding the fields' order was right - I was making a message conversion in the client (it was required by some business logic) and, as the result, the Message object was created and sent to the server. This Message object was not able to preserve the fields' order. I've changed that conversion so that the fields order wouldn't be corrupted and everything started working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted after our conversation in the comments section, the order of the fields in the [`<Parties> component block`](http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/compBlock_Parties.html) group was incorrect. The field order in a repeating group (or component block as in case of `<Parties>`) should be preserved. You can find [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.be/2011/02/repeating-groups-in-fix-protcol.html) a blog post on the subject explaining the importance of field order in repeating groups.

In your case, a client-side modification of the message screwed up the field order of the `<Parties>` group which resulted in a `Reject` message from the server.

Answer (score 0):

@TT My 10 cents. [Fiximate](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/) is your friend.

In my FIX4.4 data dictionary I can see that for message type OrderCancelReplaceRequest the tag 447 PartyIDSource is not defined. I enclose my data dictionary message.

If you need to define PartyIDSource then add it to your data dictionary.

```
<message name="OrderCancelReplaceRequest" msgtype="G" msgcat="app">
    <field name="OrderID" required="N" />
    <component name="Parties" required="N" />
    <field name="TradeOriginationDate" required="N" />
    <field name="TradeDate" required="N" />
    <field name="OrigClOrdID" required="Y" />
    <field name="ClOrdID" required="Y" />
    <field name="SecondaryClOrdID" required="N" />
    <field name="ClOrdLinkID" required="N" />
    <field name="ListID" required="N" />
    <field name="OrigOrdModTime" required="N" />
    <field name="Account" required="N" />
    <field name="AcctIDSource" required="N" />
    <field name="AccountType" required="N" />
    <field name="DayBookingInst" required="N" />
    <field name="BookingUnit" required="N" />
    <field name="PreallocMethod" required="N" />
    <field name="AllocID" required="N" />
    <group name="NoAllocs" required="N">
      <field name="AllocAccount" required="N" />
      <field name="AllocAcctIDSource" required="N" />
      <field name="AllocSettlCurrency" required="N" />
      <field name="IndividualAllocID" required="N" />
      <component name="NestedParties" required="N" />
      <field name="AllocQty" required="N" />
    </group>
    <field name="SettlType" required="N" />
    <field name="SettlDate" required="N" />
    <field name="CashMargin" required="N" />
    <field name="ClearingFeeIndicator" required="N" />
    <field name="HandlInst" required="N" />
    <field name="ExecInst" required="N" />
    <field name="MinQty" required="N" />
    <field name="MaxFloor" required="N" />
    <field name="ExDestination" required="N" />
    <group name="NoTradingSessions" required="N">
      <field name="TradingSessionID" required="N" />
      <field name="TradingSessionSubID" required="N" />
    </group>
    <component name="Instrument" required="Y" />
    <component name="FinancingDetails" required="N" />
    <group name="NoUnderlyings" required="N">
      <component name="UnderlyingInstrument" required="N" />
    </group>
    <field name="Side" required="Y" />
    <field name="TransactTime" required="Y" />
    <field name="QtyType" required="N" />
    <component name="OrderQtyData" required="Y" />
    <field name="OrdType" required="Y" />
    <field name="PriceType" required="N" />
    <field name="Price" required="N" />
    <field name="StopPx" required="N" />
    <component name="SpreadOrBenchmarkCurveData" required="N" />
    <component name="YieldData" required="N" />
    <component name="PegInstructions" required="N" />
    <component name="DiscretionInstructions" required="N" />
    <field name="TargetStrategy" required="N" />
    <field name="TargetStrategyParameters" required="N" />
    <field name="ParticipationRate" required="N" />
    <field name="ComplianceID" required="N" />
    <field name="SolicitedFlag" required="N" />
    <field name="Currency" required="N" />
    <field name="TimeInForce" required="N" />
    <field name="EffectiveTime" required="N" />
    <field name="ExpireDate" required="N" />
    <field name="ExpireTime" required="N" />
    <field name="GTBookingInst" required="N" />
    <component name="CommissionData" required="N" />
    <field name="OrderCapacity" required="N" />
    <field name="OrderRestrictions" required="N" />
    <field name="CustOrderCapacity" required="N" />
    <field name="ForexReq" required="N" />
    <field name="SettlCurrency" required="N" />
    <field name="BookingType" required="N" />
    <field name="Text" required="N" />
    <field name="EncodedTextLen" required="N" />
    <field name="EncodedText" required="N" />
    <field name="SettlDate2" required="N" />
    <field name="OrderQty2" required="N" />
    <field name="Price2" required="N" />
    <field name="PositionEffect" required="N" />
    <field name="CoveredOrUncovered" required="N" />
    <field name="MaxShow" required="N" />
    <field name="LocateReqd" required="N" />
    <field name="CancellationRights" required="N" />
    <field name="MoneyLaunderingStatus" required="N" />
    <field name="RegistID" required="N" />
    <field name="Designation" required="N" />
  </message>
```

Comment: Hi rupweb, the `<component name="Parties" required="N" />` in my case is defined at the bottom of the dictionary. I just downloaded the latest release from quickfix C++ version, and at the bottom of FIX44.xml is the `<component name='Parties'>` definition. The group element `NoPartyIds` includes field `PartyIDSource` for which the tag number is defined as 447 (`<field number='447' name='PartyIDSource' type='CHAR'>`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The field "PartyIDSource" which number is 447 is embedded into "Parties" component, so, that's not the reason...

Comment: @TT So your FIX 4.4 OrderCancelReplaceRequest message data is different to mine. Can you paste in your OrderCancelReplaceRequest message? The reason I ask again is the error message: "Tag not defined for this message type" points to something like this. Where is the tag supposed to be defined if not the data dictionary?

Comment: It isn't defined in the message itself, it is defined in the `Parties` component. Look for the string `<component name='Parties'>` in FIX44.xml, that defines the `NoPartyIDs` group. You will see the `PartyIDSource` referenced there.

Comment: Btw the error message of the OP was caused by incorrect ordering of the fields in the Parties component block.

Comment: Hah, I was half way there :)