# Validating sequence of tags in FIX message

Tags: fix-protocol

I need to validate the sequence/order in which the fields comes in a FIX message.
Is it possible to validate the sequence of tags in a FIX message using quickfix/j or Quickfix/n ?

In the messages which I'm getting from server, certain tags are in different order which is not expected. I expect them to come after certain repeating groups but they come before the repeating groups. Hence, I need to write a script which will check the sequence of incoming messages from server and compare them against the standard message definitions.

Can someone suggest any good open source libs available to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

The order of FIX tags is not constrained unless they are inside repeating groups. Your application should not be throwing any errors based on tag order.

If you are using  Quickfix/J you should switch on message validation within your [quickfix/j settings](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.0/usage/configuration.html), which will check for mandatory tags being present and tags within repeating groups being in order, but I doubt any FIX engine will check order as this is not part of the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Further to user1717259 it sounds to me like you're trying to configure your data dictionary in a particular way, and you want to have a look at something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402144/add-user-defined-fields-in-the-fix-dictionary) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682235/quickfix-doesnt-validate-the-repeating-group)